# ngFacebook does not load work in angular and throws "can't load URL" error

Tags: angularjs, facebook

My code is as shown below:

app.js

```
angular.module('quflipMobWeb', [
    'quflipMobWeb.services',
    'quflipMobWeb.controllers',
    'quflipMobWeb.login',
    'quflipMobWeb.homeController',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngFacebook'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$facebookProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $facebookProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when("/home", { templateUrl: "template/home.html", controller: "homeController" }).
        when("/login", { templateUrl: "template/login.html", controller: "loginController" }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
        $facebookProvider.setAppId('id').setPermissions(['email', 'user_friends']);
    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$window', function($rootScope, $window) {
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        $rootScope.$on('fb.load', function() {
            $window.dispatchEvent(new Event('fb.load'));
        });
    }]);
```

loginController.js

```
angular.module('quflipMobWeb.login', []).
controller('loginController', function($scope, $location, $facebook) {
    $scope.facebookClick = function() {
        // $location.path("/home");
        $facebook.api("/me").then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.welcomeMsg = "Welcome " + response.name;
            },
            function(err) {
                $scope.welcomeMsg = "Please log in";
            });
    };

    $scope.googleClick = function() {
        $location.path("/home");
    };
});
```

login.html

```
<div class="q-login-background">
    <div class="q-login-container ng-cloak">
        <p class="q-login-text"> Login through</p>
        <div class="q-facebook-button" ng-click="facebookClick()"> Facebook </div>
        <div style="font-size:12px;color:#ACACAC;"> or </div>
        <div class="q-google-button" ng-click="googleClick()"> Google </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For facebook login to work, I have even set site URL  as *http://localhost:3000/#/login*  in developer.facebook.com

But somehow it gives me the following error:

`Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.`

Is there anything missing here, which I forgot to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have your domain on **App Domain** settings section in [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com).

Put **only domain** in this secction, not the fully path. In your case, try put only `localhost`.

[image: Àpp-domain facebook settings]

Comment: You are emphasizing **only domain**, and yet you don’t seem to know what that actually means yourself. The domain name in this case would just be `localhost` - no protocol, no port.

Comment: yeah you're right @CBroe. Edited answer. thanks for aclaration.